# Updating the tables for the reports in MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I have a MicroStrategy project where the reports in that project were earlier using Teradata connections and sql. But now the requirement is to point all these reports in the project to a snowflake database instance.
The new snowflake database instance is already created. I wanted to know the ways to do this.

1. I will update the default database instance to the new snowflake connection in the 'Project Configuration'.
2. Update the Database instance in the 'Warehouse Catalog'.
3. Refresh the warehouse catalog.

With these steps will all the reports in the project get updated with the new database in the SQL with the table name being the same between Teradata and Snowflake?
Or is there any other step that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer it...

1. Create a connection/ DSN to New Database
2. Use MicroStrategy Configuration Wizard to create new Metadata, History List, Statistical repository list (1st option in the wizard).
3. Create a New Project source using the above DSN
4. Duplicate your project into this Project source.

Source: https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB44209-How-to-migrate-projects-from-one-database-to-another-in?language=en_US